# Prove that a polygon with nonnegative area is determined by at least three points.

Tags: geometry

How do you prove this statement in geometry?

> A polygon with nonnegative area can't be formed with fewer than 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's fewer than $3$ it must be $0$, $1$ or $2$...

Comment: But there's still something to show, because there exist two-point polygons on the sphere having nonzero area.

Comment: @whuber I don't think the question considers non-Euclidean geometry. But if it does then the original statement would be wrong, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Sawarnik I wasn't claiming the question concerns anything other than Euclidean geometry. Pointing out that this statement is wrong in other geometries demonstrates the logical necessity of invoking *some* axiom that is enjoyed by Euclidean geometry.